# (VBA) Trouble with Deleting a Shape Out of Specific Cell Before Placing New One

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, syntax, shapes, target

**Objective of the Code:**
On a chosen sheet, there is a column of dropdowns (with name format "Box #") that I want to be able to change and have the respective picture 3 columns over change (20 dropdowns, 20 pictures). Pictures are copied  from seed pictures lower down on the page and pasted into the companion column. Each of these pictures is given a unique name in format "Box #"

**What Does Work:**
I have two separate pieces of code that work:
Program 1) Change the dropdown menu (target) to a new name and have a picture of the same name appear in a column 3 over
Program 2) Delete a Picture in a specified cell

**What Does Not Work:**
Really just to understand VBA better, I'm trying to figure out how to plug Program 2 in at the start of Program 1 to delete the contents of the picture cell before placing a new picture. Ideally, yes, the deletion code would be a sub that's called upon, but again, just want to understand VBA better.

**Program 1)** Works

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim NewTarget As String

    Select Case Target
        Case Is = "Box 1"
            NewTarget = Target.Offset(0, 3).Address

            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(Target)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range(NewTarget).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        Case Is = "Box 2"
            NewTarget = Target.Offset(0, 3).Address


            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(Target)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range(NewTarget).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        Case Is = "Box 3"
            NewTarget = Target.Offset(0, 3).Address
            
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(Target)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range(NewTarget).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End Select

End Sub
```

**Program 2)** Works

```
Private Sub delete_picture()

Dim NewTarget As Range
Set NewTarget = [k9]

 For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
 If Not Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, NewTarget) Is Nothing Then shp.Delete
 Next
 
End Sub
```

**Combining 2 into 1)** Doesn't Work

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim NewTarget As String
Dim NewTar As Range
Set NewTar = Target.Offset(0, 3).Address

 For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
 If Not Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, NewTar) Is Nothing Then shp.Delete
 Next

    Select Case Target
        Case Is = "Box 1"
            NewTarget = Target.Offset(0, 3).Address

            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(Target)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range(NewTarget).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        Case Is = "Box 2"
            NewTarget = Target.Offset(0, 3).Address

            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(Target)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range(NewTarget).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        Case Is = "Box 3"
            NewTarget = Target.Offset(0, 3).Address

            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(Target)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Range(NewTarget).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End Select

End Sub
```

**The Error I'm Receiving:**
"Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error"

If NewTar is instead set to K9, It deletes the shape in K9, then throws the error. Debug then highlights line "If Not Intersect(shp....".

My next step will be to replace K9 with Target.Offset(0,3).Address

**What am I doing wrong?** The VBA syntax is still a little weird to me. I'm only showing code for 3 box pictures and dropdowns. I'm using cell K9 in Program 2 as a test cell. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm sorry, in the "Combining 2 into 1)" Block, NewTar = K9 for the stated error outputs

Comment: `Set NewTar = Target.Offset(0, 3)`. The `.Address` returns a `String`, not a `Range`.

Comment: @BigBen, won't that return the value of what's in the cell rather than the cell location? I guess I would need to somehow provide the cell location as a range rather than as a string like Address outputs it as.

Comment: `Set NewTar = Target.Offset(0, 3)` sets `NewTar` to the `Range` that is 3 columns to the right of `Target`. It has nothing to do with the value at all.